# C# на что можно заменить много операторов if или как их убрать в отдельный класс

Tags: c#

В коде много очень операторов if будет,как пример тут 3, можно как то укратить либо как их убрать в отдельный класс. Comand_SelectionChanged - это combobox

```
private void Comand_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (SelectedState != null)
        {
            code1 = SelectedState.Code;
            name1 = SelectedState.Name;
            if (name1 == "/bag addtoplayer")
            {
                textcomand.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                textcomand.Text = "Name";
            }
            else
            {
                textcomand.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            if (name1 == "/bag additem")
            {
                gradee.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                countt.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                textcomand.Text = "ID";
            }
            else
            {
                gradee.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                countt.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            if (name1 == "/ban chat")
            {
                ID.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                gradee.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                countt.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                textcomand.Text = "Player";
            }
            else
            {
                ID.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                gradee.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                countt.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: в этом коде немного ифов, ничего в нем менять не нужно

Comment: @tym32167 я планирую добавить 40 if

Comment: @СерегаWend O_o

Comment: супер. Мы должны вообразить код, куда вы могли бы добавить 40 ифов или вы какой то пример кода покажете?

Comment: Скорее всего вы делаете что-то не то....

Comment: @tym32167 пример кода я скинул, сейчас еще подредактриую и вы поймете

Comment: @СерегаWend, напишите хотя бы 5 ифов в вопрос, будет легче понять суть. Пока что у меня две стандартные идеи рефакторинга ифов: полиморфизм и ассоциативный массив.

Comment: @trollingchar добавил еще 1 if, так понятно ?

Comment: @СерегаWend вроде бы чуть-чуть понятнее, сейчас подумаю как можно сделать

Comment: А что там фрагменты в блоках else делают? В том смысле, какое у них назначение?

Comment: @trollingchar отображение типо либо видны на панели либо нет

Comment: То есть там получается что есть какое-то состояние которое включается при выборе команды показывает элементы а когда выберут другую команду то оно выключается и элементы скрываются и показываются новые?

Comment: @trollingchar Да как то так

Answer (score 2):

Если задача в зависимости от значения применять какие-то отдельные присвоения меняя визуал, то почему бы вам не сделать словарь `Dictionary<string,Action<T>>`.
По ключу вы получаете определенное действие, в него передаете контрол, а уже то, что лежит в делегате сделает все, что вам нужно.

В итоге все полотно if'ов заменится 2-мя строчками кода.

```
var action=_dict[SelectedState.Name];
action(ControlsToChange);
```

В каком-нибудь месте нужно лишь составить словарь:

```
Dictionary<string,Action<Control[]>> _dict=new Dictionary<string,Action<Control[]>>();
```

и наполнить его обработчиками на каждое состояние.

Я уверен, что какие-то `Action'ы` у вас будут повторяться между состояниями=> не будет дублирования кода => вместо 40 будет на самом деле 15 обработчиков.

Comment: Мне совсем не понятен ваш код. Что за что отвечает. Хотелось бы что то по проще

Comment: Вы в каком-то месте создаете словарь, где ключом является состояние, а значение метод в котором описано, что нужно сделать. Далее, просто по ключу получаете значение из словаря и выполняете метод передав ему аргументы при необходимости.

Comment: P.S Код проще некуда. Если это сложно, то проще сделать 40 if'ов. Работа со словарями и делегатами- это базис в котором выгодно разобраться.

Comment: Я никогда не работал с словарем. Не могли бы вы по подробней рассказать как это сделать

Comment: @СерегаWend https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.9.php

Answer (score 0):

Если у нас будут разные контексты, то придется сделать не одну функцию, а две, при включении и выключении.

```
class Context {
    public Action activate, deactivate;
    public Context (Action activate, Action deactivate) {
        this.activate = activate;
        this.deactivate = deactivate;
    }
}
```

Объявим словарь этих контекстов:

```
Dictionary <string, Context> contexts = new Dictionary <string, Context> ();
```

Объявим также текущий контекст, чтобы помнить, что выключать.

```
Context currentContext;
```

Для удобства сделаем смену через свойство:

```
Context CurrentContext {
    get { return currentContext; }
    set {
        currentContext?.deactivate ();
        currentContext = value;
        value?.activate ();
    }
}
```

Словарь нужно сначала 1 раз заполнить, иначе работать оно не будет. Например, так:

```
contexts ["/bag addtoplayer"] = new State (
    () => { TextCommand.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; TextCommand.Text = "Name" },
    () => { TextCommand.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; }
);
```

Дальше дело за малым - у вас в строке `command` есть команда, тогда просто пишете

```
CurrentContext = contexts [command];
```

И все работает. Если я где-то ошибся, поправьте меня.

Comment: Вообще говоря, можно пойти еще дальше и сделать контексты через наследование, но это только если обработчики включения и выключения будут повторяться.

Comment: я так и не понял зачем - Словарь нужно сначала 1 раз заполнить, иначе работать оно не будет. Comand это вообще combobox

Comment: @СерегаWend Словарь - это такая штука, которая может тебе по строке сказать какой контекст ей соответствует. Но только если перед этим в нем записано это соответствие. Если не заполнить его то кроме ошибок мы ничего не получим, сколько к нему ни обращайся. Ну не command а textcommand, как хотите так и называйте переменную.

Comment: а куда все if вбивать ?

Comment: @СерегаWend а никуда, мы от них избавились. Правда код заполнения словаря будет длинноват, но все равно короче и понятнее ифов. Если вы про тот код который был внутри, вбивайте его в эти `() => { ... }`. В первую - то что при включении, во вторую - что при выключении контекста должно быть.

Comment: @СерегаWend, если вы не знаете, что такое словарь (Dictionary<TKey, TValue>), то прежде чем продолжать работу над проектом используя выше написанный совет нужно о нём почитать и понять для чего он и как работает (как использовать). Тогда, вероятно, пропадёт вопрос сам собой, куда вбивать "if" (значения из if).

Comment: @trollingchar так погоди, я хочу наоборот избавиться от большого кода в main. Как весь этот код который ты описал отдельно выкинуть в класс ???

Comment: @СерегаWend Я пока отойду, надо работу делать, вернусь вечером, тогда продолжим

Comment: @trollingchar ок, если не сложно накидать в программу и скинуть суда буду очень благодарен

Comment: @trollingchar ожидаю ответа

Comment: @СерегаWend, ты же уже принял другой ответ

Comment: @trollingchar ответ не является правильным, я пытался сделать так. Но элементы управления должны оставать main классе.

Answer (score 0):

Если словари и прочие вещи для вас пока сложно, то вы всегда можете выделить часть логики метода просто в отдельный метод. Например

первый if

```
private void Fun1(string name)
{
    if (name == "/bag addtoplayer")
        {
            textcomand.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            textcomand.Text = "Name";
        }
        else
    {
        textcomand.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

второй if

```
private void Fun2(string name)
{
    if (name == "/bag additem")
    {
        gradee.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        countt.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        textcomand.Text = "ID";
    }
    else
    {
        gradee.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        countt.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

третий if

```
private void Fun3(string name)
{
    if (name == "/ban chat")
    {
        ID.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        gradee.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        countt.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        textcomand.Text = "Player";
    }
    else
    {
        ID.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        gradee.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        countt.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

И главный метод превращается

```
private void Comand_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (SelectedState != null)
    {
        code1 = SelectedState.Code;
        name1 = SelectedState.Name;

        Fun1(name1);        
        Fun2(name1);        
        Fun3(name1);                
    }
}
```

Comment: Это не работает если я создаю это в отдельном классе. Я делаю ссылку на обьект.

Comment: Но я незнаю как сделать ссылку на Элемент интерфейса textcomand.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

Comment: MainWindow ds = new MainWindow();  --> ds.textcomand.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;  не помогает

Comment: Передавайте ссылку на свое окно в эти функции и все дела @СерегаWend

Comment: не сработало ничего не происходит

Comment: @СерегаWend вы мне предлагаете вообразить что вы сделали и найти в этом воображаемом коде вашу ошибку? :)

Comment: как вы бы сделали

Comment: Я бы поглядел на вопрос, поглядел на ответ. Если ответ этот подходит и вы хотите задать новый вопрос - задавайте новый вопрос. Если ответ не подходит, снимаете галку, дополняете вопрос нужными деталями. @СерегаWend

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал вот так.

Определим перечисление команд которые начинаются со слеша:

```
public enum CommandType : uint
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Bag = 1,
    Ban = 2,
    // etc
}
```

И очень простой класс для определения команд:

```
public class CommandManager
{
    private static readonly Regex ParseDataCommand = new Regex(@"^\/(?<CommandKey>\w+)\s+(?<CommandData>\w+)$",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public static KeyValuePair<CommandType, string> GetCommandType(string fullCommand)
    {
        Match match = ParseDataCommand.Match(fullCommand);
        if (!match.Success) return new KeyValuePair<CommandType, string>(CommandType.Unknown, string.Empty);

        return !Enum.TryParse(match.Groups["CommandKey"].Value, true, out CommandType type)
            ? new KeyValuePair<CommandType, string>(CommandType.Unknown, string.Empty)
            : new KeyValuePair<CommandType, string>(type, match.Groups["CommandData"].Value);
    }
}
```

Далее, очень простой тест работоспособности:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> testCommands = new List<string>
    {
        "/bag addtoplayer",
        "/bag additem",
        "/ban chat",
        "/get userdata",
        "Some unusable command"
    };

    foreach (string testCommand in testCommands)
    {
        KeyValuePair<CommandType, string> result = CommandManager.GetCommandType(testCommand);
        Console.WriteLine("Command is: {0} and command parameter is {1}", result.Key,
            result.Value == string.Empty ? "Empty" : result.Value);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
Command is: Bag and command parameter is addtoplayer
Command is: Bag and command parameter is additem
Command is: Ban and command parameter is chat
Command is: Unknown and command parameter is Empty
Command is: Unknown and command parameter is Empty
```

Часть 2я. немного усложним процесс обработки команд, но упростим их вызов до 1й строки:

```
private void Comand_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SelectedState != null)
    {
        CommandManager.GetCommandType(SelectedState.Name)
            .GetCommandByCommandParts()
            .Invoke();
    }
}
```

Приступим, немного изменим наш класс `CommandManager` до следующего состояния:

```
public enum CommandType : uint
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Unknown command or is not a command
    /// </summary>
    Unknown = 0,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Some Bag, idk what is this
    /// </summary>
    Bag = 1,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Ban user or channel etc...
    /// </summary>
    Ban = 2

    // etc...
}

public enum CommandParameter
{
    Unknown = 0,
    AddTopLayer = 1,
    AddItem = 2,
    User,
    Chat
}

public class CommandManager
{
    private static readonly Regex ParseDataCommand = new Regex(@"^\/(?<CommandKey>\w+)\s+(?<CommandData>\w+)$",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

    static CommandManager()
    {
        CommandActions = new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<CommandType, CommandParameter>, Action>
        {
            {
                new KeyValuePair<CommandType, CommandParameter>(default, default),
                () =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Unknown command called with Unknown parameter.");
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static Dictionary<KeyValuePair<CommandType, CommandParameter>, Action> CommandActions { get; }

    public static bool RemoveCommandAction(KeyValuePair<CommandType, CommandParameter> type)
    {
        return CommandActions.Remove(type);
    }

    public static void AddNewCommandAction<T>(Action<T> action, KeyValuePair<CommandType, CommandParameter> type, T commandData)
    {
        CommandActions.Add(type, () => { action.Invoke(commandData); });
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Позволяет распарсить пользовательскую команду на подчасти.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fullCommand">Команда введенная пользователем.</param>
    /// <param name="ignoreCase">Игнорировать ли регистр введенной команды.</param>
    public static KeyValuePair<CommandType, CommandParameter> GetCommandType(string fullCommand,
        bool ignoreCase = true)
    {
        Match match = ParseDataCommand.Match(fullCommand);
        if (!match.Success)
            return new KeyValuePair<CommandType, CommandParameter>(default, default);

        if (!Enum.TryParse(match.Groups["CommandKey"].Value, ignoreCase, out CommandType type))
            return new KeyValuePair<CommandType, CommandParameter>(default, default);

        return Enum.TryParse(match.Groups["CommandData"].Value, ignoreCase, out CommandParameter parameter)
            ? new KeyValuePair<CommandType, CommandParameter>(type, parameter)
            : new KeyValuePair<CommandType, CommandParameter>(type, default);
    }
}
```

Так же добавим небольшой класс который расширит функционал, дабы мы не лезли вручную и не пытались найти необходимый `Action` для полученной команды:

```
public static class ExtensionCommandManager
{
    public static Action GetCommandByCommandParts(this KeyValuePair<CommandType, CommandParameter> commandKeyValuePair)
    {
        return !CommandManager.CommandActions.TryGetValue(commandKeyValuePair, out Action result)
            ? CommandManager.CommandActions[new KeyValuePair<CommandType, CommandParameter>(default, default)]
            : result;
    }
}
```

Теперь давайте все это дело соединим и сделаем небольшой тест:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> testCommands = new List<string>
        {
            "/bag addtoplayer",
            "/bag additem",
            "/ban chat",
            "/ban user",
            "/get userdata",
            "Some unusable command"
        };

        CommandManager.AddNewCommandAction(ActionBag,
            new KeyValuePair<CommandType, CommandParameter>(CommandType.Bag, CommandParameter.AddItem),
            "AddItem");
        CommandManager.AddNewCommandAction(ActionBag,
            new KeyValuePair<CommandType, CommandParameter>(CommandType.Bag, CommandParameter.AddTopLayer),
            "AddTopLayer");
        CommandManager.AddNewCommandAction(ActionBan,
            new KeyValuePair<CommandType, CommandParameter>(CommandType.Ban, CommandParameter.User),
            "SomeUserName");
        CommandManager.AddNewCommandAction(ActionBan,
            new KeyValuePair<CommandType, CommandParameter>(CommandType.Ban, CommandParameter.Chat),
            "SomeChatName");

        foreach (string testCommand in testCommands)
            CommandManager.GetCommandType(testCommand).GetCommandByCommandParts().Invoke();
    }

    private static void ActionBag(string bagData)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Bag command called with parameter \"{bagData}\"");
    }

    private static void ActionBan(string userName)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Ban command called with parameter \"{userName}\"");
    }
}
```

После чего в окне отладки увидим следующий текст:

```
Bag command called with parameter "AddTopLayer"
Bag command called with parameter "AddItem"
Ban command called with parameter "SomeChatName"
Ban command called with parameter "SomeUserName"
Unknown command called with Unknown parameter.
Unknown command called with Unknown parameter.
```

Надеюсь данный код поможет и натолкнет вас на мысль о переработке вашего кода в такой незамысловатый парсер пользовательских данных.